# Find all $n$ such that $2^n+1$ and $2^n-1$ are primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

> Find all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $2^n+1$ and $2^n-1$ are both primes .

**My Attempt:**

let $p=2^n+1$ and $q=2^n-1$

I will start with a claim.

**claim:**
$n=2\implies p=5, q=3$ is the only solution, because otherwise $2^n+1$ or $2^n-1$ would be divisible by $5$ or $3$.

if $3\mid 2^n+1\iff 2^n+1\equiv 0 \pmod 3 \implies 2^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

But i don't know how to prove this claim.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666175/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452075/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567425/42969

Comment: For the Mersenne primes, the exponent must be prime, for the Fermat primes, it must be a power of $2$. Which numbers have both properties ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are kinda on the right track. Note that one of $2^n-1, 2^n, 2^n+1$ is divisible by $3$, and one of them is never divisible by $3$. Hence if $2^n-1 > 3$, one of $2^n-1, 2^n+1$ is composite.

Comment: How did you know that one of them is divisible by $3$

Comment: They are three consecutive numbers.

Comment: $2\equiv (-1)\pmod 3 \implies 2^n\equiv (-1)^n\pmod 3 $ Then either $$\cases{2^n-1\equiv 0\pmod 3 \\ 2^n+1\equiv 0 \pmod 3}$$ Am i right?

Comment: That is correct, so which of $2^n\pm1$ is divisible by $3$ depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.